# C# Word copy style from one paragraph to another

Tags: c#, ms-word

In word I have 2 paragraphs, and I'm trying to copy formatting from one to the other.

I've tried:

```
Word.Style style = activeDocument.Paragraphs[2].get_Style() as Word.Style;
activeDocument.Paragraphs[1].set_Style(style);
```

and

```
Word.Style style = activeDocument.Paragraphs[2].Range.CharacterStyle as Word.Style;
activeDocument.Paragraphs[1].Range.set_Style(style);
```

This doesn't properly copy the style though, and the first paragraphs style is set to the default text styling. How do I get the proper styling information?

Answer (score 0):

I think paragraph[2].get_style() return *normal style (default text)* because of paragraph[2] style is *normal (default text)*!! **You change formatting text but not save it as style!** The style of paragraph[2] not change from default value. See style  name in MSWord and **create new style** then **apply** it, then **1 variant work** fine.